# How to get multiple selected values in JSP and pass it to SERVLET?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have this for each loop in jsp:

```
      <form action="genreChoose" method="GET">
        <select id="selectGenres"  multiple>
            <c:forEach var="genre" items="${genreList}">
                <option value="${genre.title}" name="genreTitle">${genre.title}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select> 
       <button type="submit">Add</button>
      </form>
```

I want to select 1 or more values from select tag and pass it to servlet. For this example i have choice between 15 genres and i want to choose 5, when button `Add`  is clicked i want to have those 5 genres in servlet to do something with them. How to do that?

Comment: give `name` to your select box.Suppose `name="select"` then get it at your backend using `String[] values = request.getParameterValues("select");` and finally loop through array to get all values .

Comment: @Swati i kinda try that but it always giving me only first selected genre. This is the code:
`String[] genres = new String[] {request.getParameter("selectGenre")};//this is name,not id
        for (int i = 0; i < genres.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(genres[i]);
        }` I'm priting just to see if it works and only prints first item that i selected.

Comment: You have use `request.getParameter("selectGenre")` which return single value .Instead use `request.getParameterValues("selectGenre");` and see onces

Comment: @Swati you are the best! Thank you